# Same css code works in codepen but not on Atom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was viewing one of the Trending works on CodePen and essentially manually typed the html, css, and javascript code into my local Atom file to get an idea of how each line works. Specifically, this code is for designing a Range slider with glowing gradient:

[Source code in CodePen](https://codepen.io/jkantner/pen/VwxeeVb)

[Photo of slider as designed in CodePen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3gPz.jpg)

When I copy the entire code into my local Atom file, the slider starts at 50% just as the CodePen file does, however when I drag the slider on my local copy, the slider moves but the glowing background (gr-glow) does not change; it remains static at 50% as if I never dragged the slider.
[Photo of local copy of slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kl35.jpg)

It appears to also work on here as well. Is this likely an Atom issue?

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() => {
    const grs = new GradientRangeSlider("#gradient-range");
});

class GradientRangeSlider {
    constructor(qs) {
        this.input = document.querySelector(qs);
        this.input?.addEventListener("input",this.update.bind(this));
        this.update();
    }
    update(e) {
        let value = this.input.defaultValue;

        // when manually set
        if (e) value = e.target?.value;
        // when initiated
        else this.input.value = value;

        const min = this.input.min || 0;
        const max = this.input.max || 100;
        const percentRaw = (value - min) / (max - min) * 100;
        const percent = +percentRaw.toFixed(2);
        const handle = 1.5 * (1 - (percent / 100)) - 1.125;
        const percentStyle = `calc(${percent}% + ${handle}em)`;

        this.input.parentElement?.style.setProperty("--percent",percentStyle);
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
:root {
    --hue: 223;
    --white: hsl(var(--hue),10%,100%);
    --gray1: hsl(var(--hue),10%,90%);
    --gray2: hsl(var(--hue),10%,80%);
    --gray7: hsl(var(--hue),10%,30%);
    --gray9: hsl(var(--hue),10%,10%);
    font-size: calc(16px + (48 - 16) * (100vw - 320px) / (1280 - 320));
}
body,
input {
    font: 1em/1.5 sans-serif;
}
body {
    background-color: var(--gray9);
    color: var(--gray1);
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

/* Main styles */
.gr-glow {
    --gradient: linear-gradient(90deg,hsl(3,90%,55%),hsl(63,90%,55%) 6em,hsl(123,90%,55%) 12em);
    --percent: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    width: 12em;
    height: 1.5em;
}
.gr-glow:before {
    background-image: var(--gradient);
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    filter: blur(0.6em);
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0;
    width: var(--percent);
    height: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.gr-input {
    background: var(--gray7) var(--gradient) no-repeat;
    background-size: var(--percent) 100%;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    width: inherit;
    height: 0.75em;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.gr-input:focus {
    outline: transparent;
}

/* WebKit */
.gr-input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background-color: var(--white);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.0625em var(--gray2) inset;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
.gr-input:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb,
.gr-input::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
    background-color: var(--gray1);
}

/* Firefox */
.gr-input::-moz-range-thumb {
    background-color: var(--white);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.0625em var(--gray2) inset;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
}
.gr-input:focus::-moz-range-thumb,
.gr-input::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
    background-color: var(--gray1);
}

/* Acccessibility */
.sr {
    clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
}

/* `:focus-visible` support */
@supports selector(:focus-visible) {
    .gr-input:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        background-color: var(--white);
    }
    .gr-input:focus-visible::-webkit-slider-thumb,
    .gr-input::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
        background-color: var(--gray1);
    }
    .gr-input:focus::-moz-range-thumb {
        background-color: var(--white);
    }
    .gr-input:focus-visible::-moz-range-thumb,
    .gr-input::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
        background-color: var(--gray1);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Range Slider With Glowing Gradient</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/css/main.css"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="">
    <label for="gradient-range" class="sr">Range</label>
    <span class="gr-glow">
        <input id="gradient-range" class="gr-input" type="range" value="50" min="0" max="100">
    </span>
</form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you linked both file, css and js into your html?

Comment: Wow...didn't realize that I didn't link the files properly. Looks like I had a few typos where the <script> was linking to the css file. Thank you!!!